# ImagePager save images to sd card?

Tags: android, image, save, pager

I have implemented a save button in my **ImagePagerActivity** however it crashes when i click the save button.

Please point out any errors I might be causing unaware or if there's another way of saving the images more effectively to the sd card. I am still a newbie to coding so please double check my work.

**ImagePagerActivity.java**

```
       .....
        Button isave;

        isave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        isave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bitmap mSaveBit = imageLoader.getMemoryCache().get(Constants.IMAGES[pager.getCurrentItem()]);
                File imageFile = null;
                if (null == mSaveBit) {
                    imageFile = imageLoader.getDiscCache().get(Constants.IMAGES[pager.getCurrentItem()]);
                }

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/HD GOSPEL LOCKSCREENS");
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    f.mkdirs();
                }
                f = new File(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "HDGL.PNG");
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    try {
                        f.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {
                    mSaveBit.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream(f));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            Toast.makeText(ImagePagerActivity.this, "Image Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
       });
```

.....

Comment: Post your StackTrace. And also check you have given `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` **permission**

Comment: yes I have that set. it compiles but when i click the save button thats when it crashes

Comment: Did you see any logcat error post that error.

Comment: here's what i saw on the logcat http://pastebin.com/D3anTNLU